# Angular 5 lazy loading not working. Shared module not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

We are trying to implement lazy load in our project. But I am having a strange error. Basically, I have created a module for a component and used loadchildren in app.module. But there is another component used in that component in Html like this

```
<cr-configure-button></cr-configure-button>
```

So for this component, I am getting this error

```
Can't bind to 'hub' since it isn't a known property of 'cr-configure-button'.
1. If 'cr-configure-button' is an Angular component and it has 'hub' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'cr-configure-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
```

For this component, I have created a shared module that is exporting this component. Please see the code below

Please help.

Thank you in advance

app.module.ts

```
 { path: 'modules', loadChildren: './hubs/hubs.module#HubsModule' },
```

hubs.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { HubsRoutingModule } from './hubs-routing.module';
import { HubsComponent } from './hubs.component';
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HubsRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],

  declarations: [
    HubsComponent,
  ],

})
export class HubsModule { }
```

shared.moudule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CrConfigureButtonComponent } from './components/buttons/cr-configure-button';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [CrConfigureButtonComponent],
  exports: [CrConfigureButtonComponent],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: you need `CrConfigureButtonComponent` in declaration of hubs.module too.

Comment: I tried that also. But same error

Comment: whats inside `CrConfigureButtonComponent` ? any third party library or not ?

Comment: I have shared module that has CrConfigureButtonComponent in declarations and exports .Imported this shared module in hubs module

Comment: CrConfigureButtonComponent is just an angular component

Comment: inside `CrConfigureButtonComponent` template what have you used?

Comment: well in this case share your stackblitz here ?

Comment: inside CrConfigureButtonComponent, there is an html button

Comment: Hey, @GaurangDhorda Thank you for the help.Here is stakblitz   https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-5-cemvxg?file=app/hubs/hubs-routing.module.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2epzx2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhubs%2Fhubs%2Fhubs.component.html here at my side its working fine!

Comment: There is some issue with angular version 5.2 for lazy loading. The code worked fine after updating the angular